# How to submit the rails3.1 engine form rendered inside the main app to be submitted to the engine's controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm building a new rails3.1 engine for commentable functionality.

I created the engine, generated the resource named `Comment`.

The engine's `config/routes.rb` has:

```
Kurakani::Engine.routes.draw do
  resources :comments
end
```

The `spec/dummy` rails app has a resource named `Post` and its routes has:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end

  mount Kurakani::Engine => "/kurakani"
end
```

I've setup the associations between the engine's Comment model and dummy rails app's Post model.

Then inside the `spec/dummy` rails app, I've rendered out the comment form in the `show` template of the Post.
The form also gets generated with its action path to `post/1/comments`.

When I run the spec, I think it tries to search for the controller inside the `spec/dummy` app itself instead of submitting to the engine's `app/controllers/kurakani/comments_controller.rb`, so I get the following error when I run the spec.

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/integration/comments_spec.rb                                                                           ruby-1.9.2-p180
No examples matched {:focus=>true}. Running all.
Run filtered excluding {:exclude=>true}

/Users/millisami/gitcodes/kurakani/app/views/kurakani/comments/_form.html.erb:3:in `___sers_millisami_gitcodes_kurakani_app_views_kurakani_comments__form_html_erb___1787449207373257052_2189921740'
F

Failures:

  1) Kuraki::Comment authenticated user creating a new comment
     Failure/Error: click_button "Create"
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       uninitialized constant CommentsController
     # ./spec/integration/comments_spec.rb:29:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

How can I specify the comment to be submitted to the engine's `comments_controller.rb` instead of the `spec/dummy` app??

If I couldn't make the problem clear, I've pushed the repo at https://github.com/millisami/kurakani

Comment: Can anyone look at it? Its banging my head!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your route for the form that is generated goes to `/posts/:post_id/comments`, which is the route defined in your *application*, but not your *engine*. Your engine only defines this route:

```
resources :comments
```

This is (almost) working because the engine sees that the application has the route which matches to `CommentsController`, it's just that there's no `CommentsController` for it to go to.

I downloaded the application from GitHub and had a play around and changed the `form_for` in `app/views/kurakani/comments/_form.html.erb` to be this:

```
form_for(Kurakani::Comment.new, :url => kurakani.comments_path)
```

This makes the test pass, but I am not sure if it actually gives you what you want. You're probably going to want to play around with that URL part yourself.

What's happening here is that this view is rendered by the main application using the `kurakani_list` helper in `spec/dummy/app/posts/show.html.erb`, meaning that any URL helper that you reference (directly or indirectly) will point to the *application* and not to the engine, like I think you want it to.

So in order to tell Rails what the true route is that we want our form to go to we *must* specify the `:url` option and tell it we want to go to `kurakani.comments_path`, rather than the `comments_path` which *may* be defined by the application.

If we wanted to do the reverse (reference an application route from within an engine), we would use `main_app` rather than `kurakani`.